# Why can I assign/compare int and char in C

Tags: c++, c

I have the code like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int c;
c = getchar();
while (c != EOF) {
putchar(c);
c = getchar();
}
}
```

The C documentation says that the `getchar()` returns the `int` value. And in the above program we have assigned `c` type as an `int`. And most importantly `EOF` is a `integer`  constant defined in the header function.

Now if the code changes to something like this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
    }
    }
```

This code also works! Wait a min, as per C documentation `getchar()` returns`int`, but see in the above code I'm storing it in `char`. And C compiler doesn't throw any error. And also in `while` loop I have compared `c` which is an `char` with `EOF` which is an `int` and compiler doesn't throw any error and my program executes!

Why does the compiler doesn't throw any error in the above two cases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C isn't dynamic, it just allows implicit casts between numeric types. The second code will interpret the character `\xFF` as EOF (on systems where EOF == -1), but the first won't, which is why `getchar` uses int.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I doesn't have to be `\xFF`, plus on machines where `char` is unsigned, it may be compiled as an infinite loop.

Comment: @Ant's I didn't downvote, but the question is a bit silly.

Comment: @let_me : no worries! I had a doubt, put the doubt here. Now a two downvote shows that my thinking is wrong! Thanks for the donwnvoters and thanks for your comment too :D

Comment: Seems like a valid, well asked newbie question. It should be UPVOTED not downvoted.

Comment: @Dough : thanks! and ya i'm a newbie in C!

Comment: Re the downvotes. The problem with question is the way it is asked. If it was just "why can I assign/compare int and char in C" then it would be a reasonable question. All the stuff about dynamic languages is asking the wrong question and/or showing-off

Comment: @Ant's: You've edited only the title, and the question which you *actually* have asked is different from the title. In fact, the code doens't  even relate to the title, in any way. Better rollback the changes you made to the title and create another topic if you want to ask why can't you compare `int` with `char`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. It simply means that the returned value which is an `int`, *implicitly* converts into `char` type. That is all.

The compiler *may* generate warning messages for such conversion, as `sizeof(int)` is greater than `sizeof(char)`.  For example, if you compile your code with [`-Wconversion`](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/NewWconversion) option with GCC, it gives these warning messages:

```
c.c:5:7: warning: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value
c.c:8:8: warning: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value
```

That means, you should use `int` to avoid such warning messages.

Comment: so which is best way to use? a `char` or an `int`?

Comment: Which also means that the code won't work. It may seem to work, but you can easily input the correct value to make it end prematurely, or if you are on an architecture, where `char` is unsigned, it will never exit the loop.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that the term "dynamic programming language" is too vaguely defined to make a such a fine distinction in this case.

Though I'd argue that implicit converting to one numeric type to another is not a dynamic language feature, but just syntax sugar.

Answer (score 3):

No. Lets look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language)'s definition

> These behaviors could include extension of the program, by adding new
>   code, by extending objects and definitions, or by modifying the type
>   system, all during program execution. These behaviors can be emulated
>   in nearly any language of sufficient complexity, but dynamic languages
>   provide direct tools to make use of them.

What you have demonstrated is that a char and int in C/C++ are pretty much the same, and C/C++ automatically casts between the two. Nothing more. There's no modification of the type system here.

Answer (score 1):

Lets rewrite your code to illustrate what's going on

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char c;
    c = EOF; /* supposing getchar() returns eof */
    return (c == EOF) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

What should the return value of this program be? EOF is not a char, but you cast it to a char.  When you do a comparison, that cast happens again, and it gets squashed to the same value.  Another way of rewriting this to make it clear what's going on is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while ((char)c != (char)EOF) {
        putchar((char)c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

EOF is getting squashed; it doesn't matter how it's getting squashed, it could be squashed to the letter 'M', but since it gets squashed the same way every time, you still see it as EOF.

Answer (score 0):

C will let you do what you want, but you have to accept the consequences. If you want to assign an int to a char then you can. Doesn't make it a dynamic language.

(As an aside, the title of this question should be something like "why does c let me assign an int to a char?" and just contain the final paragraph. But presumably that wouldn't attract enough attention. If it had attracted any upvotes then I'd edit the title, but since it isn't I'll leave it as an example of how not to ask a question.)

Comment: Lol! sorry it was a newbie question and ya sure @andy I wont keep the titles as such hereafter!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not reading 7-bit ASCII data, it is possible that \xFF is valid data.  If EOF is \xFFFFFFFF and you return the value of getchar() to a char then you can not distinguish EOF from \xFF as data.